# Accessing NULL pointers

Tags: c, gcc

This is part of my code... and i have several major problems that im stuck on...
ok most of the problem that i can see so far has been fixed... but im still lost on where to free the memory.
this is the error message when i end the program :S

```
 HEAP SUMMARY:
==15468==     in use at exit: 20 bytes in 1 blocks
==15468==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 20 bytes allocated
==15468== 
==15468== 20 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==15468==    at 0x4025BD3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==15468==    by 0x8048601: newnode (myassignment.c:27)
==15468==    by 0x804885E: insertavl (myassignment.c:88)
==15468==    by 0x8048B33: main (myassignment.c:156)
==15468== 
==15468== LEAK SUMMARY:
==15468==    definitely lost: 20 bytes in 1 blocks
==15468==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15468==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15468==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15468==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15468== 
==15468== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==15468== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 13 from 8)
typedef struct node *tree;

struct node {
   int data;
   char name;
   int height;
   struct node *left;
   struct node *right;
};




static tree newnode(int d,char n){    
   tree t = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   t->data = d;
   t->name=n;
   t->left = NULL;
   t->right = NULL;
   memoize(t);
   return t;
}

static tree modnode(int d, char n,tree t){
   if (d > t->data){
       t->data=d;
       t->name=n;
       t->right = t->right;}
   else{
       t->data=t->data;
       t->name=t->name;
       t->right = t->right;}
  return t;
}



tree insertavl(tree t, int d,const char *n){                 
   if (t == NULL) return newnode(d,*n);
   else if (t->name==*n) return modnode(d,*n,t->right);// <=========(1)
   else {                                                
      printf("went right");
      setright(t, insertavl(t->right, d,n));
   }
   return t;
}


int main(void) {
  int i = 0;
  char foo[11];
  int c;
  tree t= NULL;
  for(c=0;c<=1000;c++) {
    i = readstring(foo,10);
    if(i == 0) break;
    if (strcmp("score",foo)==0){
   int a=0;
   int point;
   char n[21];
   printf ("Enter name \n");
   a=readstring (n,20);
   printf ("Enter score \n");
   scanf("%d", &point);
   t=insertavl(t,point,n);}
   if (strcmp("highscore",foo)==0){
       printf ("%d \n", highsc(t));}

   if (t==NULL){
      printf ("false");}
    }
   return 0;
 }
```

i know my program is not efficient but i wan to fix the error first.,,any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try and reduce this to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: at line 37, you are dereferencing a NULL pointer; there's not much more to be said about that.

Comment: On a side note, are your names only 1 character?!

Comment: What is the type `tree`? Its declaration is not in the code.

Comment: Also, the title of your question is wrong, this is not about a memory leak but about accessing `NULL` pointers.

Comment: what is sssc? I don't really see how I am dereferencing a NULL pointer..in order get to modnode, t can not be NULL

Comment: I see a `malloc()` but no corresponding `free()`.

Comment: @user1516649, just read it. It says  "0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd"

Comment: In `modnode`, why the assignment `t->right = t->right;`? It doesn't do anything.

Comment: What do you expect `t->right = t->right;` to do if you earlier did `t->right = NULL;`

Comment: oh i think i got confused there..i wanted to pass connect rest of it :X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And what about checking the return value of malloc ?

Comment: ??I'm sorry i dont' quiet understand...why would i check the return value of malloc?

Comment: static tree newnode(int d,char n){    
   tree t = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   if (!t)
     anErrorAppear;
   else
    {
   t->data = d;
   t->name=n;
   t->left = NULL;
   t->right = NULL;
   memoize(t);
   return t;
   }
   return NULL;
}

Answer (score 1):

The line you highlight:

```
else if (t->name==*n) return modnode(d,*n,t->right);// <=========(1)
```

Think about what happens when `t` is a new node with both `t->left` and `t->right` set to `NULL`.

Comment: ah....ops. that's one problem solved! thank you very much! one more thing... do you know where i should free my malloc?

Comment: @user1516649 In your program you never remove nodes, but that would be a good place to free the memory allocated to them.

Comment: well the thing is i don't have to remove the node..i just have to modify or add new node. that's why im confused on where to free it

Comment: @user1516649 Then you don't have to free it, it will be freed for you by the system when the program ends.